# Binomial coefficient expansion question

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to follow this expansion (linked below) for one of my classes, but nothing I have tried is proving successful.

Any hints or help would be very appreciated.

Thanks :)

[Binomial coefficient expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvGdC.png)

Comment: I tried to edit this to include a cordial greeting, but it isn't working. Apologies for sounding abrasive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake, here is the correct expansion
$${n\choose r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac{n}{n-r}\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-1-r)!}=\frac{n}{n-r}{n-1\choose r}$$

Comment: Thank you so much @Maryam. I was really confused over whether I was missing something very elementary.